# issue with padding for container (scrollbar appears)

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup and it's all done for modern browsers. How can I modify this for getting the same for old browsers (IE7, etc.)? Is it only position absolute can?

```
<style>
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    background: darkgreen;
  }

  .sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: #bada55;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: I expect to get `.container` 100% of the window height and `padding: 15px` without scroll.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont show or say, what you expect as a result its really dificult to help but you could use css hacks for ie7 like using the same property with a " `*` " that property will only work with ie7

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding overflow:hidden to the container?